# aspnet core 2.2 External Authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

Created an Authentication Api to handle the auth for several apps.  This is a basic auth.  username and pw. No OAuth with Google etc.  The api gets called with the credentials and it responds with an AthenticationResult.  It works correctly except on AuthenticationResult.Success.  As I learned I cannot serialize the  ClaimsPrincipal.  As I am reading it seems the answer it to convert to a token.  Is this correct? The AuthenticationResult.Failed serializes w/o issue.    What is the best solution here.  I will continue to look.
thx for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## General Steps

That's correct, you'll need to complete the following steps:

1. Return a token from your authentication API.
2. Configure your application for JWT Bearer authentication.
3. Include that token as part of an `authorize` header on every request to the server.
4. Require authentication/authorization in your controllers.

There is an excellent [ASP.NET Core 2.2 JWT Authentication Tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) you should check out.

There's too much code involved to post all of it in it's entirety, but here are some key snippets (some code slightly modified for greater clarity out of context from the tutorial):

## Some Key Code Snippets

### Creating the token

```
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] 
    {
        // 'user' is the model for the authenticated user
        // also note that you can include many claims here
        // but keep in mind that if the token causes the
        // request headers to be too large, some servers
        // such as IIS may reject the request.
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
    }),
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
};
var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

### Configuring JWT Authentication (in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method)

```
var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
```

Don't forget to configure the app to actually *use* authentication in Startup.cs `Configure` method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the comprehensive answer!!!  Seems like I always learn stuff when  under a deadline!!!  Thanks againG

Comment: I'm glad it helped you! Once you're ready to move beyond just authentication, be sure to check out the [authorization docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2). The ASP.NET Core libraries really allow for a lot of flexibility and customization.

Comment: This is my first time into setting up an external server to handle things.  Documentation for that gets a little incomplete and with all the changes into core 2.2 it gets a bit trying!!  lol. Back to school!!   I got the api sending the token in the response  just need to get into the client!!   Thx G