# Angular 2+ and dotnet core 2.1 - setup authentication manually

Tags: .net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I created an angular dotnet core project, using visual studio 2017 (using the angular template) - without authentication.

I added JWT, but not sure how to implement the dotnet core identity - the login logic, and the necessary tables, without breaking any rules or standards.

What is the best way to this ?

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54837249/2116171) and the tutorial linked to the answer (which includes example solutions you can download) to see if it answers your questions. If it answers some, but not all, update here with your remaining questions and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to implement your own authentication, but it's recommended to use .net core Identity instead and override everything you'd like, .net core Identity has been implemented in a way that users can change every part of it based on their use.
You can read the code of Identity on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore) 
To use a simple authentication solution you can also use a custom Authorize middleware which gets the JWT and validate it.